# from vb.net, calling functions in a C++ dll passing WORD parameter and returning result

Tags: c++, vb.net, dllimport

im trying to call a C++ dll function from vb.NET with this definition:

HRESULT functGet(WORD R1, WORD R2, HWND hWnd = 0)

the info about the function i have is:

hWnd Specify a window handle to receive a completion notice. Option Non-zero = Asynchronous operation Zero = Synchronous operation.

R1:
1 WORD = 2 BYTE of data below
DATA1: a number to use.
DATA2: another number to use.

R2:
1 WORD = 2 BYTE of data below
DATA1: a number to use.
DATA2: another number to use.

i need to declare the function passing the parameters and get the response, but after lot of search, im stucked. My start point is this:

```
DllImport("thedll.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint:="functionToCall")>
    Public Function funtionToCall() As Integer
    End Function
```

But i don't know how to declare the parameters, and how to call the function in order to pass the parameters and get the response in the hwnd.
Also, i do not understand the option non-zero about the hWnd parameter. What is the purpose? Passing the hWnd for response or tell the function if must be done sync or async?

Someone can help me, please?

Comment: `Public Function funtionToCall(r1 as UShort, r2 as UShort, hWnd as IntPtr) As Integer`, -> `Marshal.GetExceptionForHR()`

Comment: thanks very much for your help. how to load the values in r1 and r2 as r1 and r2 must have 2 values each?

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand this: ", -> Marshal.GetExceptionForHR()"

Comment: `dim r1 as UShort = 1 << 8 Or 1` (`= 257`, `0x0101`). Since your function returns `HRESULT`, you may want to marshal the value as a managed Exception, when possible.

Comment: r1 and r2 must contains 2 values each. i do not understand how to do this with your comments

Comment: `dim r1 as UShort = 1 << 8 Or 1` sets the value `1` in the hi-byte and `1` in the lo-byte. With, e.g., `dim r1 as UShort = 2 << 8 Or 1` you get `513` (`0x0201`)

Comment: please, someone can give me a response i can undestand?